# SP WIKI: How to modify the left menu?

Tags: 2013, wiki, menu

In our WIKI we have multiple articles, but unfortunately only the five latest entries show up in the left menu (see red area below).

[image]

I tried to change this through the library settings and SharePoint Designer- I couldn't find the area where to adjust this.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the Navigation items from the **Navigation** menu under **Look and Feel** from the **Site Settings** page.

[image]

If you don't see this, then first you'll need to enable the Publishing feature from the **Manage Site Features** page:

[image]
[image]

Once enabled, go back to the **Site Settings** page and you should see **Navigation** under **Look and Feel** section.

When in the **Navigation** page you will be able to alter what appears on the left hand nav (current navigation).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your site do not have customization layout or component, I guess it is built using Enterprise Wiki site template.

The left menu is called **Current Navigation**. Click the right top gear icon > site settings > Navigation. You should see the **Current Navigation** section as below:

[image]

You can change the settings here.

Comment: Thanks MArk.
Unfortunately I don't have the NAVIGATION option under site settings.
See what I have:
[![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9W6Xd.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9W6Xd.jpg) I basically went through everything here. Thanks again for your Support! Tobias

Answer (score 0):

The Updated Pages side navigation on the Wiki Pages Library is not related to the current navigation.  To remove this you must either override the CSS via a Script Editor Web Part, or modify the underlying Master Page.

I'm re-posting the correct answer from http://stephen-white.blogspot.com/2015/05/hide-recent-updated-pages-in-sharepoint.html:

---

> If you have implemented a SharePoint 2013 wiki page library for your
>   company, you might agree with me that the recent and updated pages
>   links are an unnecessary distraction to your users.  Just because a
>   page has been updated, that doesn't suddenly make it more important
>   than any other content in the site.  The problem is that Microsoft
>   doesn't give us a supported way to remove these links.
>
> So, we add a small piece of code.  I like to have big bold commenting
>   on anything I add so that I can easily spot it later on.

```
<!-- REMOVE THE LEFT HAND NAVIGATION PANEL -->
< style type="text/css">
#sideNavBox { display:none; }
</style>
```

> You can either add it to a Script Editor web part on each page, or
>   install SharePoint Designer 2013 on your PC and add it to the master
>   page.